OPNSense port forward with masquerading
I need to setup OPNsense to route traffic from public ip to internal server connected via zerotier. I've set up port forwarding for port 5432 set up target ip and target port but have not response from that service. when I tcpdumped on target machine I see that source IP of incoming packets are public IP of requester without masquerading.
So outgoing traffic from target machine going to default gateway of that machine which is different from opnsense.
The question is - how to masquerade incoming traffic for port forwarding?
Thanks!
PS: I can easely connect to target ip and port from opnsense diagnose port.

The default is destination NAT, you need source NAT in addition.

@vidarlo so I should add NAT: Outbound rule for that incoming port? So incoming traffic to WAN port 5432 will be masqueraded before port forwarding?

How about reading the documentation?

@vidarlo Thanks for pointing to the documentation. I've read it before posting question but without any success...
As I understand outbund rule is for translating source address for outgoing packet from target machine. But I need to masquerade source address before sending packet to it because it have diffrent gateway, not opnsense.
I'm missing something... I just need more detailed answer how to do it in opnsense way... Thank you!

So, after some research I understood that for this situation I have to use HAProxy.

Created rule for wan interface allowing income traffic to port 5432.
Created virtual pool with server from zerotier with 5432 port
Created virtual TCP service on port 5432 with connection to that pool.

Now everything works fine - opnsense is receiving packets from internet, transfer it with own src address to zerotier host and forward answer to client.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.


As I understand outbund rule is for translating source address for outgoing packet from target machine.

Yes, but it doesn't actually have a strict definition on what an 'outgoing' packet means. It's a generic SNAT, and OpnSense (or pfSense) only calls it "Outbound" because that's what it is typically used for.
You can freely define it on other interfaces besides the WAN interface, and it will have the expected results – if you want to SNAT packets that are incoming through 'WAN' and outgoing through 'LAN', you just specify that in the rule.
(Though: doesn't OpnSense have a "hairpin" option in the port-forward DNAT rules? I seem to recall pfSense used to have that.)
